# No Images Over SSL in Ebay Finding API?

Tags: ebay-api

I have recently moved from HTTP to HTTPS but I'm getting security warnings because the pictures from ebay API are still transferring over HTTP. Does any API user know of a way to get `gallery url` or `picture url` over HTTPS?

I have tried making a call through `HTTPS` like this `https://open.api.ebay.com/xxxxx` but obviously it won't work. Is there a parameter option for returning `HTTPS` link?

A returned data in a successful call from [GetSingleItem API](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/callref/GetSingleItem.html) is like this:

```
<GalleryURL>
http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/pict/xxxxx.jpg
</GalleryURL>
<PictureURL>
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODUwWDgwMA==/z/xxxx.JPG?set_id=xxxx
</PictureURL>
```

Comment: my understanding is HTTPS is only supported for calls to the Trading API

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue, I used galleryURL property of SearchItem object returned by  ebay Finding API, but found that even galleryURL provides insecure link to   image, the same image available on if I replace http with https.